# Unable to query Salesforce object LoginHistory

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to create a monitor job to monitor the Login Failures in Salesforce. However, When I try to query the standard object LoginHistory, Salesforce doesn't seem to allow that. When I develop a talend job, I get a message saying `"InvalidSObjectFault"`. When I develop a batch apex data loader job, I get a message saying `"sObject type LoginHistory is not supported".`

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I executed the following query with success in Execute Anonymous :

```
for(LoginHistory log : [select Id, UserId, LoginTime, LoginType, Browser, Platform, Status from LoginHistory limit 5])
{
System.debug('>>>'+log);
}
```

Also check if you have the right permissions, here is the [API object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm) :

"*Only users with Manager Users permissions can access this object.*"